# How to clear screen in a C program in codeblocks 10.05 when used in Ubuntu 12.04(LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks

I am using codeblocks IDE 10.05.
I am facing a problem when i try to clear the screen using clrscr() defined in conio.h in a C program.

It says conio.h is not defined .

can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0):

[`conio.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) comes from the DOS/Windows world. It is neither part of the C standard, nor part of any common library on a Linux/POSIX system.

If you are looking for a way to manipulate text on a terminal display, then you should look at using the [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library, which is bundled with all modern distributions.